# How to navigate potentially being sabotaged by manager?

Tags: manager

My manager is deliberately holding back on an action that impacts my career growth (I cannot mention specifics without giving away personal info). I realize he is not a good person or trustworthy, and I am making progress on leaving the company.

I know his holding back is not in error or forgetfulness as I have sent him (gently spaced) reminders and even mentioned to him more than once during 1-1 conversations to please do the requested action. That's why I know that since he hasn't done this by now it is because he quite malicious and deliberately sabotaging me.

I am planning to leave. However, while I am here, how do I navigate being around a potentially hate-filled and spiteful person?

Comment: without knowing what your boss is doing, its hard to advise

Comment: Sorry I can't mention it, too identifying :(

Comment: then we wont be able to help you. We don't need specific, just something like "I used my boss as a reference check and they wont pick up the phone"

Comment: It's not a reference check, but a communication with an external party. I know I have legal recourse in reference checks, but I am not sure about this one.

Comment: It is really hard to give advise in a case as vague as this one.  Additionally, while it is possible that your manager is motivated by malice, it is possible that you misunderstand things, in which case the correct behavior changes - and we won't be able to help figure that out without more info.  Even if they *are* out to get you, it's pretty much guaranteed that they have some reason, and what that reason is is going to have a big impact on best strategy - again, something we won't be able to tell you without more data.

Comment: I guarantee there are things you can post that are not too identifying.  I'm not saying to give exact details on what they are or are not doing, but even things like what you're relationship with your manager has been like until now, what profession you work in, what country you're part of, and so forth.  The world is a very large place.  I suspect that details aren't as inherently identifying as you think they are... especially if your boss doesn't read StackExchange.

Comment: also, if you remove the part about your boss being filled with malice and being hateful, why would it matter? its not like the public can identify them.

Comment: Things like size of company, your relationship with others in the company, how closely you are required to work with your boss, and how critical you are to the company or to your boss's part thereof also matter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you are already planning on leaving, just be polite and do your work as you normally would.  Act like a professional.  Once you have accepted a new job, hand in your resignation and all of these issues will be history.